# What is the purpose of np.gradient() edge_order?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Simple question really. When calling the `gradient` function, what does this option do?

Also is there a Python equivalent of matlab’s del2 function?

Comment: Did you read the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html)?

Comment: Yeah but I don’t understand, hence the question.

Answer (score 3):

The key phrase from the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html) is:

> The gradient is computed using second order accurate central
> differences in the interior points ...

This means that each group of three contiguous points is adjusted to a parabola (2nd order polynomial) and its slope at the location of the central point is used as the gradient.

For evenly spaced data (with a spacing of 1) the formula is very simple:

```
g(i) = 0.5 f(i+1) - 0.5 f(i-1)
```

Then comes the problematic part:

> ... and either first or second order accurate one-sides
> (forward or backwards) differences at the boundaries.

There is neither f(i+1) at the right boundary nor f(i-1) at the left boundary.

So you can use a simple 1st order approximation

```
g(0) = f(1) - f(0)
g(n) = f(n) - f(n-1)
```

or a more complex 2nd order approximation

```
g(0) = -1.5 f(0) + 2 f(1) - 0.5 f(2)
g(n) = 0.5 f(n-2) - 2 f(n-1) + 1.5 f(n)
```

The effect can be seen in this example, copied from the docs:

```
>>> x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> f = x**2
>>> np.gradient(f, edge_order=1)
array([1., 2., 4., 6., 7.])
>>> np.gradient(f, edge_order=2)
array([0., 2., 4., 6., 8.])
```

The derivation of the coefficient values can be found [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1988-51-184/S0025-5718-1988-0935077-0/S0025-5718-1988-0935077-0.pdf).